Is using queues in embedded systems for inter-thread communication bad design?
Recently had a discussion with a colleague - is using queues for inter-thread communication (e.g. FreeRTOS) bad design for "real-time" embedded systems due to the inherent non-determinism?

Would you mind to extend the "non-determinism" point? If a queue as such were non-deterministic, it would be unusable.

@thebusybee Maybe not the queue itself but when the threads are blocked waiting for new items being put into the queue from another thread?

Queues are great.  If the thread waiting for something in the queue has something else to do then that is bad design and not the queue's fault.  Hint: the thread shouldn't have anything else to do besides servicing the queue.

Isn't this the reason we use threads? The thread waiting on the reading side has nothing else to do and is therefore supposed to block. Perhaps you want to extend your question to show the arguing in more detail.

You just have to do the real-time calculations: if the queues are periodically emptied, it is probably fine. Or otherwise if there are situations when the program doesn't have time to empty them, the whole program design is broken. Which in turn means there's a maximum size which should never be exceeded.

You can certainly use a queue inappropriately to produce a bad design, but using queues is not intrinsically bad design.
A queue is used to pass data when it can sporadically be produced faster than it can be consumed (but on average it must be consumed faster than it is produced).
The sizing of the queue, the baulk/block/timeout behaviour, the relative priority of producer and consumer threads, and the real time constraints of those threads are all important design considerations that could make or break your design, not just the decision to use a queue.
You can use a queue deterministically by setting it's length to one (or some RTOS have a "mailbox" primitive that is similar).  That is often simpler than a mutex protected shared memory and semiphore/event flag signalling to achieve the same semantics.
Normally the producer would be a higher priority than the consumer, but if the consumer may not be waiting on the queue for a period during which the producer generates multiple messages, the buffering afforded by a queue may still be useful.  Although in that case I would question the appropriateness of the thread design and priority assignment rather than the use of a queue alone.
A "good" design involving a queue should however consider the mathematics of queuing theory.
In summary, design needs to be considered holistically, using a queue in itself is neither good nor bad design and indicative of neither.
